# Proving that an element of a given group has an infinite order

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I am given the following group:
$$G = \langle x_1,x_2,x_3 | x_1^2 = x_2^2 = x_3^2 = e, \langle x_1, x_2 \rangle = \langle x_2, x_3 \rangle = e  \rangle,$$
where $\langle a,b \rangle = e$ is the triple relation, meaning that
$$aba = bab.$$

I want to prove that the element $x_1 x_3 x_1 x_2$ has infinite order. This seems to me rather trivial, since (intuitively speaking) the triple relations in $G$ cannot reduce the number of generators in $(x_1 x_3 x_1 x_2)^n$.

However, when trying to prove this formally, I could not finish the proof. I tried using induction, playing with the evenness of the number of the generators $x_1, x_2, x_3$ that appear in any power of this element, but without success.

Comment: Note that your intuitive argument would still apply even if we had the additional relations $e_1e_3=e_3e_1$.  But in that case, the group is the symmetric group on four elements, so it is finite.  Second point: the group you are looking at is a Coxeter group; this might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Coxeter group.

Let $a = x_1x_2$ and $b = x_2x_3$. Then the subgroup $H:=\langle a,b \rangle$ has index $2$ in $G$ and has the presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^3=b^3=1 \rangle$. That is just an instance of a general result for Coxeter groups, but you could prove it by direct calculation in this example.

So $H$ is a free product of the cyclic groups $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ of order $3$. Your element is $aba$ and $(aba)^n = a(ba^2)^{n-1}ba \ne 1$.

Comment: What is the general result you mention?

Comment: @HughThomas: That there is always an index 2 subgroup: the kernel given by identifying all generators.

Comment: How do you conclude that $a(ba^2)^{n-1}ba \ne 1$? Maybe $a$ and $b$ satisfy some further relations in $G$.

Comment: It follows immediately from the fact that $H$ is a free product of two cyclic groups of order $3$. So the element  has infinite order in $H$ and hence also in $G$.

Comment: I still do not understand why this element can not be trivial. How does the free product help here?

Comment: @Mike: elements of finite order in a free product have to be contained in one of the free factors. In this case, the only elements of finite order are powers of $a$ and powers of $b$.

Comment: @SteveD, you can also take conjugates of finite order elements (from one of the free factors), by any element in the free product. Having this in mind, we indeed see that $bab$ can not have a finite order in $H$.

Comment: But $a(ba^2)^{n-1}ba = aba^2b \cdots ba^2ba$ is an alternating product of nontrivial elements from the two free factors, so it is manifestly nontrivial.

Comment: @SteveD ,- Another question: What if I add to the original group $G$ the relation $\langle x_1 , x_3 \rangle = e$? Would the order still be infinite? I tried to work out a similar computation as above, but without success.

Comment: Yes that's gives you an affine Coxeter group of type $\tilde{A}_2$, which is infinite virtually abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt, could you elaborate and explain why this help to prove that the order is infinite? Also, could you give a reference to these notion, I am not familiar with them.